# Windows 8 RDP and MultiMon Support

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop

Is there any documentation on which editions of Windows 8 allow a client to connect to them using multimon support?

I know this was limited to the Enterprise and Ultimate editions of Windows 7, which has caused me great headaches when working remotely. Interestingly, the edition of the serving computer determines if RDP MultiMon works or not.

Do I need Windows 8 Enterprise, or will Windows 8 Pro allow another computer to RDP to it with /multimon?

Cheers!

Comment: Can anyone tell me if Windows 8 Professional will provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, if you are connecting to a remote **Windows 7** host using a **Windows 7** client, only the remote PC (the host you are connecting to) needs to have the **Ultimate** or **Enterprise** edition (see [this blog post](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/remote-desktop-multimon-just-kidding/)):

> ... Hidden deep inside [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions), ... under
>   “*Which editions of Windows 7 include multiple-monitor support for
>   Remote Desktop Connection?*” it admits that you need Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise ... but a bit
>   of testing confirmed that it is **the host, the machine you are
>   connecting to, that needs the extra licensing power.**

To answer your question, yes, *Windows 8 Pro* does support Remote Desktop's multiple monitor (`/multimon`) feature; you do not need *Enterprise*. Just keep in mind that **both PCs** must have *Windows 8 Pro* (or higher), or you'll have to stick with monitor spanning (`/span`).

I don't have a source-- I discovered this on a blog or forum post, but I can't seem to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Pro does allow you to connect via RDP with multimon support, so happy the feature has been enabled.

Comment: please remake your answer so it becomes more complete, with quotes or any other solid proof of your statement and/or if restrictions apply.